# AutoHotkey: calculating with mouse coordinates does not work

Tags: autohotkey

Assume that upon clicking and holding, I want to show a colored box which covers the area between clicking and releasing the left mouse button. The following simple script traces the mouse position upon clicking and releasing if `Ctrl` is hold and shows a tooltip with the covered area. Showing the box only works if I specify a fixed size for the box:

[image: red box and tooltip]

However, if I try to calculate the size of the box (uncomment the last line of code), most of the time **no box** is shown?

```
Ctrl & LButton::
    MouseGetPos, start_x, start_y

    Keywait, LButton
    MouseGetPos, end_x, end_y

    ; show coordinates for debugging
    ToolTip % "dx: " . end_x-start_x . "`ndy: " . end_y-start_y

    Gui, -Caption -Border +AlwaysOnTop
    Gui, Color, red

    ; fixed size works ...
    Gui, Show, % "x" start_x "y" start_y "w" 100 "h" 10

    ; ... but the following doesnt work
    ;Gui, Show, % "x" start_x "y" start_y "w" end_x-start_x "h" end_y-start_y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since screen coordinates can be negative, use `abs()`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Math.htm#Abs)</sup> to make a negative width or height positive:
`Gui, Show, % "x" start_x "y" start_y "w" abs(end_x-start_x) "h" abs(end_y-end_x)`

Comment: Thanks! The typo you found was unfortunately introduced by copying. But thanks to your suggestion I figured out that the absolute values should be used, since height and width cannot be negative. Could you edit your post and suggest using abs(), so that it makes sense for future readers?

Comment: Yeah `abs()` will be good if you're working with negative screen coordinates. I'll edit that in.